# Does a TLV1391 Need a Pull-up Resistor

Tags: comparator

Does a TLV1391 Need a Pull-up Resistor on its output to Provide a logic level output?

Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv1391.pdf

Is it Open-drain Or Push-Pull?

Or is this just the wrong comparator for the job of providing a rail-to-rail 5v output?

Answer (score 0):

It's open-collector so you need a pullup resistor to the desired logic level and GND has to be common with the logic ground. From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv1391.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's a real bummer I've jumped in and ordered some PCB's with no resistor there. Is the schematic the only giveaway that it is an open drain or have I missed some description in the datasheet?

Comment: @Wizzard_Dr - The product page is a bit more updated and mentions it on the name: http://www.ti.com/product/TLV1391

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. :-D

Comment: You should be able to hack a resistor in there. The open-collector is implicit in \$I_{OH} \text{ and } I_{OL}\$ - the former is 100pA so basically open. Also the latter is not particularly high at 500uA with a rather high 1.5V out, so you can't go too low on the pullup resistor.

Comment: I am struggling with it producing a really soft output from a square wave input. Is the low current capability possibly the problem? Are there any suggestions for an alternative SOIC23 potential drop-in replacement. 5v rail. 0-5v in+ 0-5v in- for 1mhz?

Comment: It's a pretty slow comparator. https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=20998&prodName=TC75S57F  I didn't check the pinout or package. You can do a parametric search at a distributor. That particular  one has push-pull output and input CM range 0 to 4.1V.

Comment: So does the Common mode input voltage mean that it is not suitable for 5v at In+ and In- at the same time?

Comment: Both inputs should be in the range 0..4.1V, which is quite a bit better than the 0..3V of the one you have.

Comment: Okay, I see. I don't really know what I'm looking for. Is it possible to have a Comparator that has inputs that can range from Vdd to Vss or is that not possible?

Comment: It would be called a rail-to-rail input comparator and they no doubt exist.

Comment: Ah. Like the https://docs.rs-online.com/b810/0900766b813814bc.pdf ? Do you reckon this would be suitable? For 1mhz?

Comment: Actually. this: https://docs.rs-online.com/ad8e/0900766b814f3c64.pdf ?